# unconfirmed transactions made 1 month ago

Tags: transactions

I have 2 unconfirmed transactions made 1 month ago, i need help !!!

2adc111438150800e1f6e2746adb4a66f7d81b77800f68585990c9fbcc418c6a

and

3a9f86a7a697c241b83b841857976aff196d8a76fc42c12be407424d14295716

Comment: your fee is too low.

Comment: i see my fee is to low but how can i edit them? i have the wallet on blockchain.info

Comment: You can't "edit" it. But you can look those answers. They explain all your options: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it